# Provide read only access only to specific View in Oracle

Tags: oracle, view, roles, sql-grant

I have 5 views in my Oracle database schema. And i need to provide read only access to only one view for user.

I am thinking below approach but not sure if its possible as i am not good in dba part.

```
a) Create a new user  or the corresponding business role APP_ROLE and assign "CREATE SESSION" rights.

b) GRANT SELECT ON <view> TO {APP | APP_ROLE}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In actual oracle versions (>=12.1.0.2) it's better to use `read` privilege:

1. [New features 12.1.0.2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/release_changes.htm#GUID-00745268-6964-4EE7-92FE-6B4B72931043)
2. [READ Object Privilege in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/read-object-privilege-12cr1#read-object-privilege)

On previous versions - yes, `grant select` is fine.

Comment: read access prevents a user from doing SELECT FOR UPDATE - good advice!

Comment: one question here instead of creating new user, cant we create new role and assign  view permission to that role?